# How to develop cross platform apps with Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, cross-platform, flash-builder

I have been throught a lot of reading and the whole thing is becoming only more confusing so I decided to ask you some stuff about Flex.

So, Flex can run in a webpage if you have Flash plugin in your browser, in an AIR container (on pc/android/IOS, but on OSX ?) and also can compile to Native IOS/Android app.
I am not sure about the last point.

If it is possible, how can I build a flex app that would run in browser with flash plugin and also be compiled to Android and IOS (and maybe Windows RT) ?
Adobe gives you Flash builder, do you also need the Flex SDK ? Is it doable with the Eclipse Flex plugin ?

Thank you for your help and sorry if it is a bit messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, Flex can run in a webpage if you have Flash plugin in your
>   browser, in an AIR container (on pc/android/IOS, but on OSX ?) and
>   also can compile to Native IOS/Android app. I am not sure about the
>   last point.

This is mostly correct.  Flex can run in a web page using the Flash Plugin, which is widely available on desktop browsers.  For all intents and purposes, you should assume your mobile users do not have a Flash Plugin installed on their mobile browsers.

It is true using AIR you can create desktop applications for PC and Mac; OSx is indeed supported.   You can also use AIR to create Mobile applications on Android, iOS, and Blackberry Playbook.  So, iOS is indeed supported.  Windows 8 UI/Metro support for AIR is expected 1st quarter of this year.  I suspect we'll also see AIR support for Blackberry 10; but nothing has been formally announced that I'm aware of.

---

**Update: 3/2014**
Adobe has abandoned plans for Windows 8 UI / Metro support.  Windows Phone 8 support is a very common feature request, though, so [vote](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3648920) for it if you want it.

BlackBerry 10 does indeed support Adobe AIR.  Here is a [link to the SDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/air/).

---

> If it is possible, how can I build a flex app that would run in
>   browser with flash plugin and also be compiled to Android and IOS (and
>   maybe Windows RT) ?

Flex is primarily a framework for creating business applications.  A slightly different component set is offered for desktop applications and mobile applications.  Part of this is due to screen size; and part due to performance.  A big DataGrid with dozens of columns, for example, is not conducive to the screen size of your mobile phone.

---

**Update 3/2014:**

A mobile optimized DataGrid was donated to the Apache Flex Team, and it should be available in current versions of the SDK.

---

In the end; you should not plan on using the same exact application for both your Desktop/browser app and the mobile app.  But, you can share some amount of code.  I would target to share 80% of the code.  Move the shared code into a library project; which you can then use on both your mobile application, your desktop application, and your browser based application.

> Adobe gives you Flash builder, do you also need the Flex SDK ? Is it
>   doable with the Eclipse Flex plugin ?

Flash Builder is shipped with the Flex SDK.  And Adobe Flex ships with the AIR SDK [Note: Apache Flex does not ship w/ the AIR SDK due to licensing differences; but there is a handy installer].  Flash Builder, also, is an Eclipse plugin and can be installed into any eclipse instance you wish.

You do not need Flash Builder to create a Flex Application.  You can use command line tools and other IDEs, such as IntelliJ, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flash Professional, you can package and export to a number of platforms using AIR. You *can* port to both Android or iOS (as a native app), in addition to creating a .swf file that can be embedded onto a webpage - all using the one application (go 'File' > 'Publish Settings' then change the player target).

I'm not sure whether the same options are available in Flash Builder, (appears to be possible - 
[adobe website](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6b84a753ecd210fd-7fb8a08d12114b6a4cf-8000.html)) but not other IDE (such as Eclipse) or framework should be needed.

You may want to consider an alternative development and deployment strategy depending on your requirements, e.g. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) which should offer support for a greater number of devices.

Comment: Do you have a source for the fact that PhoneGap supports a greater number of devices?  Also, Flash Builder is an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: [AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices.html): iOS, Android, Blackberry Tablet OS... [Phonegap](http://build.phonegap.com/): iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Blackberry 5/6/7, webOS and Symbian